# Android Honeycomb CalendarView doesn't respect xml properties

Tags: android, android-widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have the following code in my xml:

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/main_calendar"
    android:showWeekNumber="false"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="650dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor="@color/black_shadow"
/>
```

The width and height are respected, but showWeekNumber and selectedWeekBackgroundColor are not. It still shows the week number and the selected week is still the default blue color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this control is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting: you must explicitly provide the layout_width and layout_height (not match_parent / fill_parent / wrap_content). I covered it here:
[Android 3.0 CalendarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027960/android-3-0-calendarview)